# Can I say "for a vacation" to emphasize "not a business trip" in the sentence below?

Tags: vocabulary

This is the original sentence: "I came to Italy last year for a business trip."

can I say: "I came to Italy last year for a vacation." ?

I want to emphasize "not a business trip".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either *for vacation* or *on vacation* would sound good to me (rather than *for a vacation*). Also note that *came* is only appropriate if it is already known to your audience that you were (or still are) in Italy. Otherwise use *went*.

> I went to Italy last year for vacation.
>
> I went to Italy last year on vacation.

Comment: I confess that I have never come across **for vacation**. I note the Google Books Ngram Viewer does record uses of the expression, although **on vacation** is eight times more popular. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+vacation%2Con+vacation